# Click event function -- separate clicks

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/3eMGR/16/

I'm trying to make it so that on the first click it shows row 2 and then on the second click is shows row 3.

How do i make two separate events?

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be the same click handler, but you can use a variable to keep track of the click count.

```
var clickTarget = 2;
$("button").click(function () {
  var selector = "." + clickTarget.toString();
  $(selector).css("display","inherit");
  $(selector).show();
  clickTarget++;        
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XXxEN/)

Comment: By the way, `1` isn't a valid class name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $(".2").show();
  $('button').unbind('click').click(function(){
    $('.3').show();
  });
});
```

However, a better way of doing what you want is to actually add divs dynamically when you want to add a row.  This is illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtBac/1/).

(I'm assuming you actually want to add a row, as per the button's text.)

Also, stop using the `id` attribute for more than one element.  The id is supposed to be **unique**.  Use the `class` attribute for styling sets of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your class names are invalid, by the way. They must start with a `-` or a letter. I suggest you fix them.

Anyways, you can just remove the class of each `.hidden` element, one-by-one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".hidden").first().removeClass('hidden');
    });
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/3eMGR/20/**

Answer (score 0):

Please check thi **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eMGR/21/)** This will dynamically keep on adding the rows as much as you want.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
                $row = $('div.row:first').clone();
                $('div.wraper').append($row);
            });
```